How to make Widget texts horizontally from Navigation Menu
I have my 'Navigation' Menu as 'Footer Menu' widget with the following items:

HOME
COACHING
SPEAKING
ABOUT
BLOG
QUIZ
CONTACT

I can see some samples that looks like this:
https://i.sstatic.net/MOzYd2pB.png
but all I'm getting is like this: (removed the QUIZ, btw)
https://i.sstatic.net/xF0W62Ri.png
Menu:
https://i.sstatic.net/tC5N63Yy.png
Widget:
https://i.sstatic.net/IYxqQFfW.png
Sending also my dividers marked as RED:
https://i.sstatic.net/FrEuywVo.png
PS: My experience to WordPress is close to none, most of how I redesign my page is from google searches only. Please be patient on my ignorance. I have decent experience with HTML but not on applying it to WordPress.
I was hoping to make it horizontal with proper spaces as this will serve as my footer on every page.

The menu appears squeeze because The widget has less width as compared to the one with which you want to match the design, so if you adjust the widgets then you will achieve your desired results.
